# Laravel filament Relationsmanager pivot update with attributes updates Ingredients table

Tags: laravel

I created a IngredientsRelationManager inside the RecipeResource: i see the table fine and get the add new ingredient button and modal:
for some reason it is creating a record in the Ingredients table instead of the pivot
and then adding it to the recipe_ingredient table as a new record with a new ingredient.

pivot relationships are
Recipe Model:
public function ingredients()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class, 'recipe_ingredient', 'recipe_id', 'ingredient_id')
->withPivot('quantity', 'unit');
}

Ingredients Model:

public function recipes()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'recipe_ingredient', 'recipe_id', 'ingredient_id')
->withPivot('quantity', 'unit');
}

code:

```
{
    protected static string $relationship = 'ingredients';

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $ingredients = Ingredient::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Select::make('ingredient_id')
                    ->placeholder('Select Ingredients')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->columnSpan(1)
                    ->required()
                    ->options($ingredients),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('quantity')->default(1),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('unit')->default('1'),
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling the relation resource with an create ou atach action ?

Comment: with the attachaction, I can attach to recipe_ingredient with the pivot attributes but , if i want to edit/change the ingredient name it updates it in the ingredients.name instead of the recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id, it updates the pivot attributes correctly

Comment: I see, I have solved this with mountUsing, see the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can load the form fields values passing the values with the method `mountUsing`:

```php
Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
      ->modalWidth('l')
      ->form(function ($action) {
            // fields of the form
      })
      ->mountUsing(
         fn($record, $form) => $form->fill($record->pivot->toArray())
      )
```

Comment: thanks for the direction, i fixed it with:    ->using(function (Model $record, array $data): Model {
                        $record->pivot->update($data);

                        return $record;
                    }),